# Load Netplan yaml file from other directory apart from "/etc/netplan" in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop

Tags: 22.04, network-manager, netplan

System - Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop
Netplan renderer - NetworkManager

Usecase -

1. By default, there is a netplan yaml `01-network-manager-all.yaml` file in /etc/netplan.
2. On boot the netplan is applied.
3. During runtime, there is a need to apply another netplan file `02-network-manager-all.yaml` that is kept at `/home/$USER/ProjectX/02-network-manager-all.yaml`

Due to security factors, it is not possible to write directly to the file, since all the files after bootup will be in read-only mode, except the `/home/$USER/ProjectX/02-network-manager-all.yaml` file.

So during runtime, this file can be updated and when it is updated, need to apply the configuration.

Is it possible to load the `02-network-manager-all.yaml` file from the specified location rather than copy to `/etc/netplan` and do a `netplan apply`? If possible, How to do it?

Looks like there were options like `sudo netplan apply -c /path/to/file`
But, it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a symlink - this would probably be the preferred way of doing this:

```
ln -s /home/$USER/ProjectX/02-network-manager-all.yaml /etc/netplan/02-network-manager-all.yaml
```

Then `netplan` would see this file normally in `/etc/netplan`, even though the actual file is located in `/home/$USER/ProjectX`.

Comment: The symlink option works, but is there any other way to update the default path of netplan files ?

As I understood, the netplan will look for the files in {run, etc, lib}/netplan 

But can this configuration be changed so that permanently it will load from any location specified ?